# jQuery Simple Multiplication Form (onkeyup)

Tags: jquery, calculator

I'm trying to get this jQuery calculator to work, but it's not. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#height-input').keyup(function() {
        var a = $('input#diameter-input').val();
        var b = $('input#height-input').val();
        var c = 0.139885;
        var d = 42;
        $('div#barrels-result').val(a * a * b * c);
        $('div#gallons-result').val(a * a * b * c * d);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xxac8/

Comment: Can you please show us your HTML?  It could be as simple as a mistype. Or it's what @Barmar said.

Comment: `.val()` is for input elements. Use `.text()` for DIVs.

Comment: It looks like you already have an answer, but I'd like to mention that in general you should also say what is currently happening, what part is not working, and what you want to happen. This makes it much easier to help you than just saying "here is my code, find out what's wrong, tell me what the solution is".

Comment: Hi Zhihao, sorry about that. I thought you could understand what I was doing without explaining it. For the future, I'll explain. :) It seems like Kevin Bowersox figured it out!

Answer (score 3):

The [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method is primarily used to get/set the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.  When setting the content of elements you want to use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#height-input').keyup(function() {
        var a = $('input#diameter-input').val();
        var b = $('input#height-input').val();
        var c = 0.139885;
        var d = 42;
        $('div#barrels-result').text(a * a * b * c);
        $('div#gallons-result').text(a * a * b * c * d);
    });
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xxac8/2/

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now. I knew it was something to do with that part, so that's good :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.text()` to set the contents of a DIV, not `.val()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#height-input').keyup(function() {
        var a = $('input#diameter-input').val();
        var b = $('input#height-input').val();
        var c = 0.139885;
        var d = 42;
        $('div#barrels-result').text(a * a * b * c);
        $('div#gallons-result').text(a * a * b * c * d);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/xxac8/1/)